# If $X$ is orthonormal then why $I = X^T X \neq X X^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If matrix $X$ is orthonormal then why $$I = X^T X \neq X X^{T}$$? In class I heard that it's because X has orthonormal columns, but not rows. I do not know what it implies and how to go about this explanation to understand it. I know what "orthonormal" means, but I guess I am confused about the effect of ordering here, what ordering implies here and why $XX^T$ is not the same as $X^T X$ and does not equal to $I$ for orthonormal matrices...

Comment: If $X$ is a orthonormal square matrix, then one must have $X^TX=XX^T$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: @YohanRoth A critical piece of information is missing in your question. You need to add to it whether $X$ is square or rectangular. Also, the matrix is usually said 'orthogonal' rather than 'orthonormal'. So it would be useful to know what you mean by an 'orthonormal' matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

The columns are orthonormal since both have norm $1$ and the first column is orthogonal to the second. However, the rows are not orthonormal since the last row has norm $0$.

With this matrix $X$, we have $X^TX = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = I_{2 \times 2}$, but $XX^T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \neq I_{3 \times 3}$.

If you add the requirement that $X$ is a square matrix, then you can show that $XX^T = I$.

Comment: can you please provide example when $X^T X = X X^T$?

Comment: Take literally any square orthonormal matrix. The trivial example would be $X = I$. Of course, there are infinitely many others.

Comment: orthonormal in columns or rows? based on what prof said this is what matters...

Comment: Notice that the $(i,j)$-th entry of $X^TX$ is the inner product between the $i$-th and $j$-th columns of $X$. So $X^TX = I$ requires each column to have norm $1$ and every pair of columns to be orthogonal, i.e. $X$ should have orthonormal columns. Similarly, $XX^T = I$ requires each row to have orthonormal rows. So, a matrix $X$ which satisfies $XX^T = X^TX = I$ would need to have both orthonormal columns and rows.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in that comment, the matrix can in general be nonsquare. Let's take the silliest example $$x=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ This has orthonormal columns, since there is only one column. But $x^Tx$ isn't even the same dimensions as $xx^T$. $x^Tx=1$ while
$$xx^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$